# cannot resolve symbol OnEditorActionListener

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textUri);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener l){
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
});
```

that is all the code that really matters. I am trying to listen to a input from a `Textview` but it says the `setOnEditorActionListener` can't be resolved. I organized all my imports, searched the web everything and it just wont work. I just switched to Android studio and it says the symbol cant be resolved. very annoying.

Comment: what exactly will the code inside do, what do you want to check for?

Answer (score 4):

Well first of all your brackets don't seem to be in the right place. I think this is what you mean:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textUri);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did this method change in Android Studio 2.0? I still get the issue with `setOnEditorActionListener` not being recognised even as I copied your refined code. (I did replace `textUri` to the id of my EditText).

Comment: Can confirm AS throws a cannot resolve symbol error at setOnEditorActionListener... is there a fix for this ?